# Safe voltage for hydrolysis of water - teacher demo

Tags: voltage-regulator, current-transformer

I am a science teacher and looking to perform an experiment with my students.

I do not have much background in electricity.

My students will be performing hydrolysis of water using a 9v battery.

The separation of oxygen and hydrogen is very slow using a 9v battery and great for a student inquiry lab.

After the lab, I wanted to do a teacher demo with a greater voltage that is “safe” so I could separate more hydrogen and oxygen atoms.

I will be placing the live wires in a beaker and collecting the gasses in test tubes.

What would be a cheap transformer that has a higher voltage, but still safe for me to place the wires in a beaker of water?  Links or product names would be appreciated.

Comment: It ain't the voltage, it's the current.  Little 9 V batteries don't provide much current.  A 6 or 12 V power supply that can supply an ampere or so should do fine.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I used to use a 12V battery charger like you would use to charge a car battery.

Comment: AC/DC wall adapters or wall warts would work.

Comment: Are you aware that you'll need a DC supply for electrolysis and not an AC transformer?

Comment: Add a little bit of salt to your water to reduce the resistance.

Comment: What's the age of the students?

Comment: Students are in middle school.  The science team has not done a hydrolysis lab in the past, so this would be our first year doing it.  The lab is for our chemical reactions unit and collecting the hydrogen in a small test tube is the end goal for the teacher demo.  The 9v batteries for the students are perfect, but we wanted to collect more hydrogen in a test tube than a 9v battery can collect in a single period to ignite showing a second reaction to fire.  Would a 6/12 Volt 500 mA sealed lead acid battery charger with alligator clips work?

Comment: I remember using my model train power supply. It survived this but not my experiments with electromagnets.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers.  I don't know any electricians and have asked workers at Home Depot and Lowes, with little support on what is safe enough.  Please understand that the science team know the hazards of electricity and water.  We would like to use a greater, safe amount of current and not blow a circuit.  Would this item have a safe enough current?  https://www.batterymart.com/p-6v-12v-500ma-sealed-lead-acid-battery-charger.html?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=6v-12v-500ma-sealed-lead-acid-battery-charger&creative={creative}&device=c&network=o&matchtype=e

Comment: Or, would a cheap car battery charger work best?  We tried the 9v batteries with baking soda and it seemed to do the same trick as the salt.

Comment: My train supply used a rheostat to control the speed. I think any 9 to 12V DC supply would work if you put a power resistor in series to limit current. Not something Lowes is likely to have.

Comment: If you work in a high-school I would expect your physics department to have adjustable bench power supplies with current limit.set say 9V and minimum current limit then slowly increase the current limit watching the water all the time so it does not bubble too furiously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I asked about the student ages was that I wondered just how much chemistry teaching you could pile into this. But given "middle school" I gather this is more about just trying to get their attention at all and to try and get them self-motivated. The social milieu is so distracting during that period of time that this alone can be a frustrating process.

Here, all I want to do is to provide something to inform you about the required voltage and to discuss some thoughts I have about getting younger students interested in pursuing science with their own energy and motivation (and not just pushed into it.)

The first step in working out the required voltage is something called the Gibbs energy. I won't belabor it much here, but refer you instead to this answer for [determining the standard Gibbs free energy for water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/8793). There, you can see that at \$25\,^\circ\text{C}\$ water's value is \$-237.13\:\text{k}\frac{\text{J}}{\text{mol}}\$. Avogadro's number, (\$6.02214086\times 10^{23}\:\frac{\text{molecules}}{\text{mol}}\$), provides the number of molecules per mole. Knowing that, and knowing you need two electrons per molecule (one for each hydrogen atom), this works out to:

$$\begin{align*}V&=\frac{-237.13\:\text{k}\frac{\text{J}}{\text{mol}}}{2\:\frac{\text{electrons}}{\text{molecule}}\cdot 6.02214086\times 10^{23}\:\frac{\text{molecules}}{\text{mol}}\cdot 1.60217662\times 10^{-19} \frac{\text{coulombs}}{\text{electron}}}\\\\&\approx 1.22883962\:\text{V}\end{align*}$$

This does NOT take into account other factors due to inefficiency or the fact that you are starting with a liquid (lower entropy) and going to a gas (higher entropy.) But it does tell you in broad strokes that you don't need a high voltage. \$2-3\:\text{V}\$ is more than enough and certainly \$6\:\text{V}\$ would be an over-voltage beyond any factors related to inefficiencies, enthalpy, or entropy.

It's not clear to me why you aren't using a [Hoffman apparatus](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/hoffman-electrolysis-apparatus-2/p-4431212) for the demo using larger current compliances than a \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery can provide. It's the right piece of equipment to use, if you can afford it.

By the way, in 6th grade we were allowed to make smoke bombs (I used iodine crystals as part of my choice there.) I think students at that age or a little older need fire, smoke, light. Long term "future value" ideas don't motivate because it is too far out into the future and students have to "bang their heads against a wall" to learn and it's not fun unless they can get some immediate personal benefits. (You can't get them started with "when you get older you will be glad you learned this stuff.") I believe your job should NOT be to ***eliminate*** all risk in this process, but instead to ***mitigate*** the risk as much as reasonably possible without losing the educational and motivational values. In my last year of high school chemistry, I made nitroglycerin and mercury fulminate (in class in a school with about 2,000 students in all four grades.) We also made large crystals out of aluminum foil wrapped around styrofoam balls and put together with wood rods. We then irradiated the crystals using a klystron on the table in the front of the room while we ran around with watt-meters measuring diffraction. These things made a huge difference in my life.

Of course, being careful applies to you as much as it should for the students. So do be careful when you are generating a lot of gas. Providing enough voltage will be the least of your problems. Current compliance is important and getting a consistent conductance in the water (using salts) and avoiding the generation of gases you do not want (such as chlorine, brown's gas, etc.) Adding sodium chloride (salt) to the water to improve the conductivity will yield chlorine mixed with the hydrogen, for example. My recommendation is that you research this entire topic and learn from the pros. Making gas ***fast*** carries risks and you need to be aware of them, how to detect problems, and how to properly use the results with lowered (but always non-zero) risks to yourself and others. Put in the time, both in studying the mistakes and successes of others but also in performing your experiments privately to make sure you know the range of results to expect before performing them in public and in class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response.  Very informative and a lot for us to consider.  We will continue to read up on it and might have to put it off until next year after we have come up with the best experience.  Maybe the teacher demo doesn't need to happen.  We were just thinking that middle school students remember more and are more impressed when demos have something to do with heat and chemical reactions.  I can just see a middle school student trying the teacher demo at home, even if we don't show them what the wires are plugged into, and hurting themselves.

Comment: @FrankCereghino Glad to hear it may have helped some. I really tried, as an outsider willing to give time after school, to get students at our local high school interested in science. Part of the difficulties had to do with the students themselves. Part, with the administration and their willingness to risk bringing in outsiders (risk avoidance by the principal is easier than risk management.) At least one their science teachers was "mailing it in" for the students, assigning lots of lab work and spending his own class time on a computer ignoring the students. Too many barriers, in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As JRE pointed out in one of the comments, it isn't the voltage, it's the current.  You will need some minimum voltage, to break the hydrogen/oxygen bonds.  Check with a chemistry teacher or chemistry textbook for the gory details.

When I was in elementary school, in the early 1960s, I did it at home with (as I recall) a 6V hotshot battery and a couple of copper wires.  It might have been a 12V battery, now that I think about it.

I was working from one of the myriad boy's books on electricity, I don't remember which one.  The book mentioned that one of the leads would get a dull look, from the reaction between copper and oxygen, while the other would stay shiny, and I can confirm that result.